Terraform with Jenkins Infrastructure
I have to create an infrastructure pipeline. I created an EC2 instance with Jenkins and Terraform. When I create the pipeline on Jenkins, terraform init works but after that terraform plan loads and never stops. And my Jenkins server works extremely slow. I waited like 1 hour to finish the job but nothing. I had to stop the server from AWS.
ec2test.tf:
resource "aws_instance" "myec2test" {
  ami           = "ami-0c101f26f147fa7fd"  
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  tags = {
    "Name" : "JenkinsInstance"
  }
}

providers.tf:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

Jenkinsfile:
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    PATH = "{$path}:${getTerraformPath()}"
  }
  stages{
    stage('terraform init') {
      steps {
        sh 'terraform init'
        sh 'terraform plan'
        sh 'terraform apply -auto-approve'
      }
    }  
  }
}
      
def getTerraformPath() {
  tfHome = tool name: 'terraform', type: 'terraform'
  return tfHome
}


loads and never stops any console output ? you can test the same in github actions it should work fine... I see no reason with the code you provided why that will fail

If you sh 'terraform apply -auto-approve' then you can remove sh 'terraform plan' anyway.

It works the same, nothing changed, still loads and doesn't end
